# how do i append to associative array in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make this exercise work but it won't work like I expected to. What I want is that the user enter his/her name and grade and that the program appends the entries and print them to the document.
the html output is like this:

```
Your name is: Robert and your grade is: B
Robert B
Name: Robert, Grade: B
Name:0, Grade: Robert
Name:1, Grade: B
```

here is the code:

```php
<form class="" action="test.php" method="post">
  <label for="Name">Student Name:
  <input type="text" name="studentName" placeholder="Your name">
  </label>
  <label for="Name">Grade:
  <input type="text" name="studentGrade" placeholder="Your Grade">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

$studentName = $_POST['studentName'];
   $studentGrade = $_POST['studentGrade'];
      $grades = Array($studentName => $studentGrade);
      array_push($grades,$studentName,$studentGrade);
      echo('Your name is: '.$studentName.' '.'and your grade is: '.$studentGrade.'<br>');
      echo ($grades[0].' '.$grades[$studentName].'<br>');

  foreach($grades as $x=>$x_value)
  {
  echo "Name:" . $x . ", Grade:" . $x_value;
  echo "<br>";
  }`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in php can basically act in two ways:

- As a list. Each entry of the array is just a value, and it is numerically indexed.
- As a record. Each entry in the array is a field on the record. Each of the fields can be referred to by a name.

And they can be of both types at the same time, that's whats happening here.

First you are creating an associative array (the second type) where the field named `Robert` (the key) has the value `B`, that's what the following line means.

```
$grades = array($studentName => $studentGrade);
```

Next you are appending the values of the two variables to that same array.

```
array_push($grades,$studentName,$studentGrade);
```

Now the array has become mixed, since the variables didn't have any key associated with them. As they were the first values in the "list mode", they were assigned `0` and `1`. So the array now contains:

```
Array
(
    [Robert] => B
    [0] => Robert
    [1] => B
)
```

That might explain your loop output. The statement `echo ($grades[0].' '.$grades[$studentName].'<br>');` works as expected, but it's just a happy accident.

This is oversimplified, you can read the whole [array reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) at the php site.

One last note: Since arrays can be used as records, you might want to structure them another way. Instead of using variables as keys (that you can do in certain situations) you might want to use fixed keys like so:

`$grade = array('name' => $studentName, 'grade' => $studentGrade);`

Now you can append each record to a list:

```
$classGrades = array();
// Same as array_push, append to the list
$classGrades[] = array('name' => 'Robert', 'grade' => 'B');
$classGrades[] = array('name' => 'Joe', 'grade' => 'D');
```

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the explaination. But the reason i put variables instead of hard coding the values is because the users can be multiple entries.

Comment: hello again i edited the code but i get this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/php/test.php on line 52
Name:0, Grade:Array. And it doesn't append to the array wen i enter more students, line 52 is the foreach loop i changed $grades for $classGrades.

Comment: i forgot  also i changed the array append string to $classGrades[] = array('name' => $studendName, 'grade' => $studendGrade);

Comment: can someone help me with this question i have been receiving a temporary ban because of my title question i have edited all my past questions but this is a though one after multiple edits i still got 0 points. Ill appreciate your help